# Observable return vs generic discrepancy

Tags: typescript

Is it considered bad practice to do something like so?

I initially say the observable is of type UserCreationResponse, but then use map to return a `User`. This is convenient for my use-case, as the json response is automatically mapped to a UserCreationResponse, and then when I subscribe to the observable I get the user. But I wonder if it could be misleading to somebody reading the code?

```
  signup(email : string, password : string) {
    return this.http.post<UserCreationResponse>("https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key="+this.apiKey, {
      email: email,
      password : password,
      returnSecureToken : true
    }).pipe(catchError(error => {return throwError("pipedErrror"+error.toString())}),
      map(resData => {
        const expirationDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + +resData.expiresIn * 1000);
        const user = new User(
          resData.email, +resData.localId, resData.idToken, expirationDate

        )
        this.user.next(user);
        return user;
      }));
```

Comment: No, that's exactly what map() is for and what observables allow. I would avoid side effects in a map() though, and would prefer using tap() for the side effect. I would also avoid the catchError(), which doesn't seem to have any useful purpose.

Comment: @JBNizet thank you that makes sense! I know, I'm just practicing/playing around :) So to summarize, I should use tap when I want to add side-effects (or the data, but without changing its type, although map is preferable then), map when I want to change the type, including its type, right?

Comment: map() is used to transform an observable<x> into an obervable<y>, by passing a function that transforms each emitted x into an y. tap() is used to trigger a side effect every type an even is emitted, without changing anything to what the observable emits.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense!

Comment: I assume I could also use map() to keep observable<x> as observable<x> but change some value? Eg: .map(x : number => x + 1)

Comment: Yes, of course. x and y can be the same type.